# UISlider: Apply resistance to drag

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, slider, uislider

Is there a way to apply resistance to a `UISlider`'s thumb drag? (Apple seems to do this in the AirPods Control Center UI; however there is not much on the internet about such a property being added to a `UISlider`)

Comment: how would you define a "resistance"? For example: you have a control over UISlider value with `func setValue(Float, animated: Bool)`, and you can get continuous updates, so user dragged by X points, you get an update, divide that amount (say) by 10, and set the value to what you want, not what user did. Is that the resistance you are looking for?

Comment: What I would do is create my own slider in which I would override the touch methods in which I would manipulate the touch input before using it to move the slider’s handle to give the effect of resistance. I do this all the time with pan gestures that dismiss modal views to make it harder to drag the further the user gestures. But I always opt for ground-up custom UI components so the choice would be easy for me.